# Strange error when adding #include <string>

Tags: c++

I have the following very simple application that compiles and runs fine:

EDIT: changed the example to be simpilar to end confusion of the real issue

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as I add `#include <string>` (and not even reference std::string), it fails to compile and I get the following error:

`/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/allocator.h:82 error: expected template-name before '<' token`

Along with about 456 other, similar errors.

Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Line 82 of `/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/allocator.h` references the template `__glibcxx_base_allocator` at the location of the error. That template is defined in `bits/c++allocator.h`. When I search the system for that file, I get 3 hits, but none of them are in `/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/` as one would expect.

I have version 3.1.6, 4.1.1, and 4.3.2, but not 4.1.2 as the rest of the includes I am using. I am not sure which one is being used (if any, however, I don't get any error for an unknown file), but it seems the problem may stem from this.

Comment: Additionally: I just use `g++ hello.cc -o hello` to compile, nothing fancy

Comment: Can you post the entire file that fails?

Comment: What is the output of `g++ --version`?

Comment: Where in the file are you adding `#include <string>`? Somewhere near the top? Are you putting it on a line of its own?

Comment: @yan That is the entire file, @Johnsyweb Version 4.1.2, @Mark I add it right after `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: steveo255, I meant the entire file that is causing g++ to fail, not the one that works fine.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you put the `#include <string>` statement on the 1st line?

Comment: Yes, the error comes no matter where the include is, and just for more information, it fails the same way, but with less errors (5 vs 457) if I `#include <vector>`

Comment: And why aren't you using `iostream` and `cout`, since you're building C++ here?

Comment: It was an example, just including string, iostream, or vector causes the problem. The printf statement is inconsequential.

Comment: Interesting. Which OS is this on and how did you install each of the GCC versions? If you could share the **full** output of `g++ --version`, that would also help.

Comment: @steveo225: Any updates? I don't think this question can be answered in its current form.

Comment: Nothing new. Still trying things, but I am almost out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the installed development packages are not correct or incomplete (not to be confused with corrupt). Forcing g++ to use different include versions corrects that:

`g++ -nostdic++ hello.cc -o hello -I/usr/include/c++/3.4.6`

All the alternative directories (4.1.1, 4.1.2 and 4.3.2) are incomplete causing inappropriate files to be included causing the unusually errors. For example:

`/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/allocator.h` requires `__glibcxx_base_allocator` located in `bits/c++allocator.h` which is being included from either `/usr/include/c++/4.1.1` or `/usr/include/c++/4.3.2` and appear to be incompatible. Forcing the compiler to use the only complete set of includes rectifies this.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everybody. After many days of working towards an answer, I finally figured it out and thought I would share my findings.

Comment: There is a typo its **-nostdinc++** not -nostdic++

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly g++ is detecting `.cc` as a C source file, not C++ and passes it through to gcc instead of compiling as C++. You can easily test by renaming your file to `hello.C`. There's also a language parameter to g++ you can use.

EDIT: This seems to work fine in g++ 4.2 with a `.cc` extension so that might not be it. Do you have any other headers included you aren't showing us? They could be interfering with `<string>`.

EDIT2: Alternatively your headers might not be set up right. Does this work:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I doubt it, as it's throwing an error about expecting a template name. Also, .cc is a common c++ extension.

Comment: I also doubt it. This isn't my actual application ***shock*** but my real one uses classes and inheritance with no problem, just seems to be STL

Comment: No, no other includes, and your example failed with the same errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this have been heard of to occur when the C++ standard library headers are corrupted/not fully installed – maybe there is even a message referring to a missing include among your 456 other errors.

In any case, make sure that `libstdc++-devel`, resp. the package containing the C++ standard library header files of your distribution, is properly installed.

Comment: I did recently make sure the correct version was installed, then reinstalled it, not saying the package on disc isn't corrupted somehow. Also, I checked the entire build log, no complaining of missing files, and most of the errors were `invalid use of undefined type 'struct std::allocator<char>'`

Answer (score 0):

This could be error caused at preprocess stage. Just preprocess your cpp file by passing flag -E to gcc and Look at the place the compiler complains.

Comment: I tried that, and got a large file output, especially since the application does nothing. I didn't see anywhere in the output where the pre-processor complained and nothing was sent to stderr, but I do admit I am unfamiliar with that particular output.

Comment: I don't mean preprocessor error, but rather error introduced after preprocessor did it's job. Just consider what effect after preprocess will be on code if you have such a stupid macro as  "#define public private". Your code probably won't compile.

Comment: Just look in preprocedd file line 82 of /usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/allocator.h. If the line looks different, than you have somewhere macro that altered the line

Answer (score 0):

Check your include path.  The paths can be specified as environment variables or specified on the command line.  You could be using an include file from a different compiler or different version of the same compiler.

Also, try using `<cstdio>` rather than `<stdio.h>`.

Another suggestion:  change <> to "".

Comment: The problem isn't with stdio.h, that works fine, the problem is with any STL include, like string, vector, iostream, etc. g++ --version reported 4.1.2 which is also the version folder where include files are found, so I am pretty sure that is matching up.

Comment: @steveo255: Are you sure that is not where the problem is? Have you tried using this C++ header rather than the old C one?

Comment: The problem is not with printing, I changed the example to reflect this (no more stdio.h or printf). The problem is when I include any STL header, it won't compile and generates the same error.